Python script not initiated at reboot cron
I have a Python script which runs fine in the terminal like
python3 /home/pi/script.py
However, when issueing the following in crontab -e
@reboot sleep 60 && python3 /home/pi/script.py
It does not work, neither when I start manually, nor at sudo reboot.
My goal is everytime the system (Rasberry Pi) turns on, the script is activated.
Any clue to where a mistake may be? I have applied chmod to the .py script, but it did not change the result.
Edit: it's a simle py script that activates a single GPIO pin on the board.

Not without knowing what it does/tries to do, in other words without seeing it. Does it require a TTY? Is it trying to open a graphical user interface?

That missing info aside: I'm fairly certain that this is a duplicate.

This question is similar to: Why crontab doesn't execute a scheduled bash script?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Since we don’t have access to your system, we expect you to do a bit of debugging before you post a question.  Main thing: do you know that your script isn’t running, or just that it isn’t doing what you expect it to do?   Have you tried adding logging to your script?   Have you tried writing a script that just writes a message to a file, and running that script through @reboot?   Also try writing a shell script that writes logs messages and invokes your Python script, and run that script through @reboot.
